# Webjobs Method Indexing - Dependency Injection Exception IConfiguration

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

.NET Core 2.2, WebJobs SDK v3.0

I initialize my host like this

```
        HostBuilder builder = new HostBuilder();
        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, configApp) => {
            configApp.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);
            configApp.AddJsonFile(
               $"appsettings.{context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json",
               optional: true);
        });

        builder.ConfigureWebJobs((context, configure) => {
            configure.AddAzureStorage();
            configure.Services.AddSingleton(context.Configuration);
        });

        builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
            services.AddSingleton(context.Configuration);
        });
```

My webJob function to process messages in a queue looks like this :

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("queuename")] CloudQueueMessage queueMessage, 
  TextWriter log, IConfiguration configuration)
```

When my host starts I get an exception

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.FunctionIndexingException: 'Error indexing method 'Functions.ProcessQueueMessage''

InvalidOperationException: Cannot bind parameter 'configuration' to type IConfiguration. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using static functions and parameter injection, you can use a full class and constructor injection.

```cs
services.AddScoped<Functions>()
services.AddSingleton(context.Configuration);

...

public class Functions
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _Configuration;

    public Functions(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _Configuration = configuration ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));
    }

    public void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("queuename")] CloudQueueMessage queueMessage, 
      TextWriter log)
    {
       //
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Alex, did you try the code? because at my side, constructor DI or parameter DI  for IConfiguration cannot work.

Comment: We have this code running in multiple web jobs. I can look up the bootstrapping later to check if there is anything special in the startup. Now that I think about it, you need to add the functions class to DI as scoped to make it work.

Comment: @AlexAIT, thanks very much if you could provide a simple example. I always get errors when using constructor DI for IConfiguration.

Comment: Did you add `IConfiguration` to the DI? `services.AddSingleton(context.Configuration);` I am not sure I will be able to set up a full sample in the next few days.

Comment: @IvanYang I just created a small sample application for webjobs with IConfiguration in Constructor DI. https://github.com/LXBdev/WebJob-netcore-sample

Comment: Glad I could help :-)